# css trick, line behind elements

Tags: css

## line behind elements

i have a `tr` with 3 columns, i want a line behind column values like :

```
--column1----------column2--------------------column3------
```

and if i want a vertical line over column 1, how can i make it?

```
   .
column1             column2               column3
   .
   .
   .
column1             column2               column3
   .
   .
   .
column1             column2               column3
   .
   .
   .
column1             column2               column3
   .
   .
   .
column1             column2               column3
   .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it helps you.

```css
body{
  background:white;
}
table{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2;
}
tr td{padding:5px;}

td{
  background:white;
}

#line{
  position:absolute;
  top:38px;
  left:56px;
  width:1px;
  height:124px;
  border-left:1px dashed black;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div id="line">

</div>
<table cellspacing="15">
<tr>
 <td>column1</td> 
 <td> column2</td> 
 <td>column3</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>column1</td> 
 <td> column2</td> 
 <td>column3</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>column1</td> 
 <td> column2</td> 
 <td>column3</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>column1</td> 
 <td> column2</td> 
 <td>column3</td> 
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: thanks, so helpful